# cxx compiler suggests "use quotes instead": compile option to not distinguish between quotes and angles?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

I use an mpicc compiler from openmpi 4.1.5 to compile my source files on an ubuntu system.

My source code consists of a single line of code -- a header to a third-party library called deal.II:

```
//step-1.cc
#include <deal.II/grid/tria.h>

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

I use a very simple CMakeLists.txt to link my executable against deal.II. Everything works, but now I want to use the tool include-what-you-use [include-what-you-use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use). I pass the include-what-you-use binaries to cmake as

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE = /path_to_iwyu_executable ..
```

I can then compile my program by calling make. Then, I get the following error

```
Error running '/calculate/simon/software/iwyu/build/bin/include-what-you-use': warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-placement-new' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-literal-suffix'; did you mean '-Wno-literal-range'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-class-memaccess'; did you mean '-Wno-class-varargs'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
In file included from /calculate/dealii-9.4.0/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu22.04-skylake/gcc-12.3.0/dealii-9.4.0-kxrbkaijxclrdrwwu5bxlavjzueiierv/share/deal.II/examples/step-1/step-1.cc:4:
In file included from /calculate/dealii-9.4.0/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu22.04-skylake/gcc-12.3.0/dealii-9.4.0-kxrbkaijxclrdrwwu5bxlavjzueiierv/include/deal.II/grid/tria.h:20:
/calculate/dealii-9.4.0/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu22.04-skylake/gcc-12.3.0/dealii-9.4.0-kxrbkaijxclrdrwwu5bxlavjzueiierv/include/deal.II/base/config.h:540:12: error: 'mpi.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#  include <mpi.h>
           ^
```

However, the file <mpi.h> is in the same directory as

```
/calculate/dealii-9.4.0/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu22.04-skylake/gcc-12.3.0/dealii-9.4.0-kxrbkaijxclrdrwwu5bxlavjzueiierv/include/deal.II/base/config.h
```

which is obviously found by include-what-you-use.
So it is clear to me why config.h is found and mpi.h not, although both are in the same directory.

Comment: You could tell the compiler to add that directory to search for "standard" headers. Usually that's the `-I` (upper-case i) option passed on the command line.

Comment: As for the question about `<mpi.h>` not turning into `"mpi.h"` that the standard behavior. `#include "mpi.h"` will always look in the same directory first, and if not found look through the system paths (which can be added to with the `-I` option). Unfortunately the opposite isn't true for `#include <mpi.h>`, it will only look in the system directories.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In my case, <mpi.h> is a file contained in the external library and, as I said, in the same folder as the file that includes <mpi.h>. So there is no workaorund in my case?

Comment: As part of building the third-party library, perhaps you should install it? How do you configure/setup the third-party library? Can the library itself be built correctly, does the problem only happen when you try to use it (include its header files into your own code)?

Comment: You need to add `-I/path/to/the/folder/that/has/mpi_dot_h/in/it` to your command line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, the third-party-library is built correctly. Also if I link my executable against the library, everythink works. Now I want to use a tool called include-what-you-use, which results in such an error above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that detail, and any more details that might be useful to know.

Comment: Show *your* code which includes a file from the directory where `mpi.h` lives, and show *your* compilation command.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Well, my "code" consists of a single line code -- a header of the third-party library which includes the metioned mpi.h.  Probably not so easy to narrow this down for a more precise question here.

Comment: You are wasting your time and everyone else's. If your code consists of one line, **show that line**. Don't write **about** that line. Just show it, exactly as it is.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I edited my question with more details. Can you help?

Comment: OK great. You wrote `#include <deal.II/grid/tria.h>`. Why didn't you write `#include <tria.h>`? What was stopping you?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I think the CMakeLists.txt contains an incldue directive only to "/path/to/deal.II/". Why does that matter?

Comment: I see there is some new information about include-what-you-use which was not there before (but which should have been there from the first edit). I have no idea how include-what-you-use works and how it could possibly mess your include path. "base/config.h" could have been found because *it* was included with a quotes or with a long path or whatever (*not* `#include <config.h>`) but how include-what-you-use is related to that I have no idea.